# Безопасность shared_ptr во многопоточной среде

Tags: c++, многопоточность, shared-ptr

Скажите, пожалуйста, что говорит `Стандарт C++17` про гарантии `shared_ptr` во многопоточной среде?

Возможна ли ситуация гонки, при которой разделяемый объект уничтожается, а указатель продолжает жить?

Я полистал `Стандарт`, но ответа не нашел.

Comment: [All member functions (including copy constructor and copy assignment) can be called by multiple threads on different instances of shared_ptr without additional synchronization even if these instances are copies and share ownership of the same object. If multiple threads of execution access the same shared_ptr without synchronization and any of those accesses uses a non-const member function of shared_ptr then a data race will occur; the shared_ptr overloads of atomic functions can be used to prevent the data race.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

Comment: что ты имеешь в виду под «разделяемый объект уничтожается, а указатель продолжает жить»? под это определение и без всякой многопоточности какое-нить `delete ptr.get();` попадает...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, существует мнение, что атомарного счетчика недостаточно для того, чтобы гарантировать безопасность разделяемого указателя в многопоточной среде. Есть даже подробные статьи, которые объясняю, почему это так. Я хочу понять, действительно ли `Стандарт` утверждает, что использование `shared_ptr` во многопоточной среде является безопасным. Если `Стандарт` такое мнение явно не выражает, значит это мнение является ошибочным плодом домыслов.

Comment: @MGNeo *"Есть даже подробные статьи"* Можно ссылки?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, https://habr.com/ru/post/311560/

Comment: @MGNeo Сейчас [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14485302/2752075) прочитал примерно то же самое. Это полностью совпадает с тем, что написал dIm0n. Видимо в первом комментарии я недостаточно точно выразился.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, и каков же вердикт?

Comment: Так dIm0n уже все написал, добавить нечего.